# Grails MongoDB FindAll does not work for special characters

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, findall

I've been trying to add search functionality to my grails project

Here's my domain class

```
class Resource {
    String mimeType
    String resourceUrl
    String website
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and here's my controller

```
class ResourceController {
def report()
    {
    def website = params.website
    println "inside report " + website
    def res = Resource.findAllByWebsite(website)
    int noOfResources = res.size()
    println noOfResources
    }
```

This code works for values of website without any special characters like www.google.com but  for some reason whenever there is any special characters in the website valuelike ? or anything, it doesnt fetch anything from the database. Please suggest me an alternate approach.

I tried this as well: `def res = Resource.findAllByWebsiteLike(website)` but it didn't work too.

Comment: Did you try escaping the special characters (i.e., using '\?' instead of '?', etc...)?

Comment: I did. But the value of website stored in database is without any escape characters. It didnt work. I am looking for an alternative approach for findAll that allows special chars

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a regex search?

such as :

```
def searchMap
searchMap.put(fieldSearch, [ '$regex' : website, '$options': 'i'] )
def res = Resource.collection.find(searchMap)
```